# Designing an Android calculator using eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, calculator

i need some insight to an issue.i have designed an android calculator using eclipse. Nothing fancy and not too complicated. If i perform an operation, when i click the equals to button, the answer pops up, no problems. But if i want to carry out another calculation, if i click another number, it is added to the previous result rather than the display being cleared for the new number. I have tried some stuffs but i could not get it right.

My question, how to clear the display after a calculation, on the new number click.

Edit from comments:

This is a little snippet;

```
@Override public void onClick(View view) { 
   Editable window = value.getText(); 
   switch (view.getId()) { 
     case R.id.button1:
          isResult = false; 
          window.append("1"); 
          break;    
     case R.id.buttonAdd:
          arithmetic = new AddArithmetic(window.toString());    
          value.setText(""); 
          isResult = false;
          break; 
     case R.id.buttonEquals: 
          String result = arithmetic.calculate(window.toString()); 
          value.setText(result); 
          isResult = true;  
          break; 
   }
```

still doesnt clear the display

Comment: This is a little snippet;
@Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
  Editable window = value.getText();
  switch (view.getId()) {
  case R.id.button1:
   isResult = false;   
   window.append("1");
   break;  
                case R.id.buttonAdd:
   arithmetic = new  AddArithmetic(window.toString());  
   value.setText("");
   isResult = false;
   break;
                case R.id.buttonEquals:
   String result = arithmetic.calculate(window.toString());
   value.setText(result);
   isResult = true;   
   break;
               }
still doesnt clear the display

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having a boolean that is set to true when you hit the equals button. Other buttons would check the boolean and if it's true, clear the textview and set the boolean back to false.

Comment: please can you give an example